# Problema con mi código, me piden ordenar tres enteros en Python sin uso de condicionales, todo está bien creo pero me bota un error al enviarlo

Tags: python

```
def ordenar_enteros(a: int, b: int, c: int)->str:
    x = int()
    y = int()
    z = int()

    a = max(x, y, z),
    c = min(x, y, z)
    d = (x + y + z)
    e = d - a
    b = e - c,

    return(str(a + b + c))
    pass
```

No se ordenan correctamente los tres enteros de mayor a menor
Excepción `TypeError` en la ejecución:

> TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'")

Comment: tienes que usar tuplas?

Comment: No, el único requisito es que estén ordenados de mayor a menor.

Comment: ¿No puedes usar simplemente `return str(sorted([a, b, c]))` o necesitas especificamente sea con max y min?

Comment: Necesito específicamente max y min, sorted se encuentra en la lista negra junto a if, for y while

Comment: Buen día, has hecho una buena primera pregunta incluyendo un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y la descripción del problema. Aún así permíteme recomendarte leer las secciones [ask] y [tour] para que te familiarices con las normas de la comunidad y de paso obtener tu primer medalla. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay algunos errores en tu función, en primer lugar, los argumentos de tu función son `a`, `b` y `c` y defines los atributos `x`, `y` y `z`, pero no los utilizas, deberías pasar los argumentos a esos atributos:

```
def ordenar_enteros(a: int, b: int, c: int)->str:
    x = a
    y = b
    z = c
```

Las comas que pusiste al final de las líneas donde recalculas `a` y `b` crean tuplas, y por eso recibes el error, hay que quitar esas comas.

Y la línea `return(str(a + b + c))` lo que va a hacer es devolverte la suma de `a`, `b` y `c` como un `string`, es decir, en caso de que uses `ordenar_enteros(5,2,8)` devolvería `'15'`. Lo que tienes que hacer es convertir cada elemento a `string` (Aunque no se bien si lo que esperas que el resultado sea una tupla o un simple `string`, yo supongo que una tupla por lo que en lugar de los `+` se deben utilizar comas `,`).

```
# En caso de que desees recibir los dígitos juntos
return (str(a) + str(b) + str(c))

# En caso de que desees recibir una tupla
return (str(a), str(b), str(c))
```

Y por último, no necesitas `pass`, esta sentencia es una sentencia tipo `null` que no haría nada ([Este](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/pass-statement) artículo explica lo que hace `pass`), pero como utilizar `return` no hace falta ponerlo.

Ejemplo completo devolviendo una tupla:

```
def ordenar_enteros(a: int, b: int, c: int)->str:
    x = a
    y = b
    z = c

    a = max(x, y, z)
    c = min(x, y, z)
    d = (x + y + z)
    e = d - a
    b = e - c

    return (str(a), str(b), str(c))

ordenar_enteros(5,2,8)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
('8', '5', '2')
```

**Edición:** En caso de que no quisieras utilizar los atributos `x`, `y` y `z` podrías hacerlo únicamente con `a`, `b` y `c` pero si modificas una de estas variables las otras no tendrían el resultado correcto, por lo que tendrías que recalcular las 3 variables al mismo tiempo

Ejemplo:

```
def ordenar_enteros(a: int, b: int, c: int)->str:
    a, b, c = max(a, b, c), a + b + c - max(a, b, c) - min(a, b, c), min(a, b, c)
    return(str(a), str(b), str(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución:

```
def ordenar(a, b, c):
    mayor = max(a,b,c)
    menor = min(a,b,c)
    medio = list(set([a, b, c]) - set([mayor, menor]))[0]
    return menor, medio, mayor
```

Esta retorna una 3-tupla con los elementos (menor, medio y mayor).

Con `max()` y `min()` encuentro el mayor y el menor elemento. El elemento medio lo encuentro por diferencia entre los dos *set*, uno formado por `{mayor, menor}` y otro por `{a, b, c}`. La diferencia es un *set* de un elemento, que convertimos en lista para extraer su primer y único elemento.